Unable to reproduce graph of sterile neutrino production
As a computational project, I've been trying to reproduce figures 3 and 4 of this paper which show the production of sterile neutrinos in the presence of neutrino self interactions as a function of the dimensionless parameter $z=\frac{1\text{MeV}}{T}$ and the distribution function $f_{v_s}$ as a function of $x$ where $E=xT$.I have spent quite a while on this but for some reason get results that do not match either figure. I will outline the definitions of the functions in my question for clarity, my question is located below. My question is relatively short/simple, please do not be fooled by the length of the post.
It begins with adding the term $\frac{\lambda_{\phi}}{2}\nu_{a}\nu_{a} \phi \subset \mathcal{L}$ to the SM Lagrangian with $\phi$ a new scalar mediator for neutrino self interactions.
We have the Boltzmann equation describing sterile neutrino production:$$\frac{d}{dt}f_{v_s}=\frac{\Gamma}{4}\sin^2(2\theta_{eff})f_{v_a}$$
or using the parameter $z$ in the paper,
$$\frac{d}{dz}f_{v_s}=\frac{\Gamma}{4Hz}\sin^2(2\theta_{eff})f_{v_a}$$
where in the temperatures of interest, $H(T)=(\frac{8\pi^3 g_*}{90})^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{T^2}{m_{pl}}$

$f_{v_a}$ is the Fermi Dirac distribution ($f_{v_a}=\frac{2}{e^\frac{E}{T}+1}=\frac{2}{e^x+1}$),

$\sin^2(2\theta_{eff})=\frac{\Delta^2\sin^2(2\theta)}{\Delta^2\sin^2(2\theta)+\frac{\Gamma^2}{4}+(\Delta \cos(\theta)-V_T)^2}$, $\Delta=\frac{m_4^2}{2E}$


($m_4$=mass of the sterile neutrino)

$V_T$ is the thermal potential defined by:
$V_T=V^{\phi}_{T}+\frac{G_F}{M_W^2}ET^4$ ($G_F$=Fermi constant, $M_W$=W boson mass)

with $\omega=\sqrt{m_{phi}^2+p^2}$.

When $m_{\phi}\gg T$, the first term in the integral can be neglected and the second can be Taylor expanded to give $V^{\phi}_T\approx \frac{7\pi^2 \lambda_{\phi}^2 ET^4}{90m_{\phi}^4}$. The approximation is best for $\frac{m_{\phi}^2}{4ET}>100$ but adding more terms in the Taylor expansion makes it more accurate. (Desmos example here)
They link this reference for the for the computation of $\Gamma_{\phi}$:

$$\sigma(\nu_{a}\nu_{a} \leftrightarrow \nu_{a}\nu_{a})=\frac{\lambda_{\phi}^4s}{128\pi((s-m_{\phi}^2)^2+\frac{m_{\phi}^4\lambda_{\phi}^4}{(32\pi)^2})}$$ with $s=2E_{1}E(1-\cos(\theta))$ and $1$ denoting the target.

If we neglect the mass of the neutrinos in question we
can compute and simplify
$$\Gamma^{\phi}=\int \frac{d^3 p_1}{(2\pi)^3}\sigma f_{v_a}=\frac{\lambda_{\phi}^4 T^2}{(8\pi)^3E}\int du \frac{u(u\text{ln}(1+e^{-u})-Li_2(-e^{-u}))}{(u-w)^2+(\frac{w\lambda_{\phi}^2}{32\pi})^2}$$ where $w=\frac{m_{\phi}^2}{4ET}$ and the integral on the RHS can be shown through simple variable substitution. In the case where $w$ is very large, we have the approximation $\Gamma^{\phi}\approx \frac{\lambda_{\phi}^4 T^2}{(8\pi)^3E}\frac{7\pi^4}{240w^2}=\frac{7\pi}{7680}\frac{\lambda_{\phi}^4 ET^4}{m_{\phi}^4}$. I made a Desmos program for this showing that this approximation holds well, mostly in the regime $w>23$ (though this varies with $\lambda_{\phi}$).
And similar to $V_T$, $\Gamma=\Gamma^{\phi}+\Gamma^{SM}$ where they give $\Gamma^{SM}=G_F^2 ET^4$
Now for my question: it is not too difficult to see that the peaks in $\frac{df_{v_s}}{dt}$ occur when $V_T =\Delta cos(2\theta)$. In the heavy mass case, as I outlined above, we have
$$V_T \approx \left(\frac{7\pi^2 \lambda_{phi}^2}{90m_{\phi}^4}+\frac{G_F}{M_{W}^2}\right)ET^4=\tilde{V} ET^4,$$
so when $V_T =\Delta \cos(2\theta)=\frac{m_4^2}{2E}\cos(2\theta)$, $E^2T^4=\frac{m_4^2}{2\tilde{V}}\cos(2\theta)$ and with $E=xT$ we have $$T=(\frac{m_4^2}{2x^2\tilde{V}}\cos(2\theta))^{\frac{1}{6}}.$$ If we also use the approximation for $\Gamma$ outlined above, we get $$\Gamma=(\frac{7\pi}{7680}\frac{\lambda_{\phi}^4 }{m_{\phi}^4}+G_F^2)ET^4=\tilde{\Gamma} ET^4.$$
Putting this together, we can estimate
\begin{align}
\frac{df_{\nu_s}}{dt}|_{V_T=\Delta \cos(2\theta)}&=\frac{\Gamma}{4}\left(\frac{\Delta^2\sin^2(2\theta)}{\Delta^2\sin^2(2\theta)+\frac{\Gamma^2}{4}}\right)f_{v_a} \\
&\approx \frac{\Gamma}{4}\left(\frac{\Delta^2\sin^2(2\theta)}{\frac{\Gamma^2}{4}}\right)f_{v_a}\\
&=\left(\frac{\Delta^2\sin^2(2\theta)}{\Gamma}\right)f_{v_a}\\
&=\left(\frac{\Delta^2\sin^2(2\theta)}{\tilde{\Gamma} ET^4}\right)f_{v_a}\\
&=\left(\frac{m_s^4\sin^2(2\theta)}{4\tilde{\Gamma} E^3T^4}\right)f_{v_a}\\
&=\left(\frac{m_4^4\sin^2(2\theta)}{4\tilde{\Gamma} x^3T^7}\right)f_{v_a}\\
\end{align} allowing us to estimate the location and magnitude of the peak purely algebraically, using the formula for peak temperature given above.
The article analyzes 3 cases:

I will focus on case A, with $m_{\phi}\approx 3.5\text{GeV}$ and $\lambda_{\phi} \approx 0.4$, where the approximations above hold very well at times of interest.
Using the approximations, I get:
$T\approx 56\text{MeV}$
$z\approx 0.0178615$
At this temperature, $g*\approx 14.8$ so $H\approx 1.64\text{e}-12 \text{eV}$. I put everything together to get an estimated
$\frac{df_{\nu_s}}{dz}|_{V_T=\Delta cos(2\theta)}=484\text{e}3$ (using the equation for $\frac{df_{\nu_s}}{dt}$ and simply dividing by $Hz$)
I use MATLAB to compute this exactly (i.e. I do not use the approximations, I use exactly what the paper outlines--the axes are the same as the figure below):

which supports my estimations. However, the paper gives this plot (figure 3):

which does has a peak at a much different $z$ value and much different amplitude. It goes without saying
my replicaton of figure 4 (computation of $f_{\nu_s}$)in the paper is orders of magnitude larger than theirs.
My conclusion is that the paper computes their figures not using the exact formulas they lay out. My suspicion is that their forms of $V^{SM}_T \approx \frac{G_F}{M_W^2}ET^4$ and $\Gamma^{SM}\approx G_F^2 ET^4$ do not hold at high temperatures (at least near the peaks). I am a student and have not yet studied QFT so this is something I could easily be overlooking. I've verified my work dozens of times and unless I'm losing eyesight and somehow am overlooking something, it must either be the case that a) their results are wrong, or, more likely, b) I am using formulas they laid out (which I suspect to be the SM neutrino thermal potential and reaction rate above) in a regime where they do not hold, or am missing something not mentioned. I have spent several days verifying that I am performing my computations correctly and it does not look like this is the issue. I would greatly appreciate any help.
